# Get element by tag (with obscure character)

Tags: javascript

I could use a little help defining the method of getting a tag name when the tag name contains an obscure character.

```
artist=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("content:encoded")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

I tried and failed with:

```
artist=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("content" + : + "encoded")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

The full js currently here. i want to also get the contents of the `<content:encoded>` tag that is also present in every item.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://doobox.co.uk/rss/page1/files/blog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");

i=0;

$(document).ready(function() {
displayItem()
});



function displayItem()
{
artist=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("category")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
year=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
txt="Artist: " + artist + "<br />Title: " + title + "<br />Year: "+ year;
document.getElementById("ShowLatestBlog").innerHTML=txt;
}


$('.back').click(function() {
  if (i<x.length-1)
  {
  i++;
  displayItem();
  }
});



$('.forward').click(function() {
if (i>0)
  {
  i--;
  displayItem();
  }
});



});
```

Comment: You are parsing XML here, correct?

Comment: Yes i am starting to build a custom feed for my blog.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are dealing with XML:

```
getElementsByTagNameNS('http://example.com/namespace/of/content', 'encoded');
```

See also: [a reference to the DOM method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagNameNS)

Answer (score 0):

when trying to retreive the contents of the xml tag `<content:encoded>` i dont acctually look for the full tag name like that, Just "encoded" eg:

```
content=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("encoded")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```